# How do I set the circle radius in a Forest tree drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, dimensions

I have following code to generate a tree using the forest package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle,draw}
  [A
    [B
      [C
        [E]
        [F]]
      [D]]
    [G
      [H]
      [I
        [J]
        [K
          [L]
          [M]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The resulting tree drawing looks like this:

[image]

You may notice that the circles surrounding each node differ slightly in size. This is most noticeable in the case of neighbouring nodes H and I, and L and M.

It could be argued that this is desirable behaviour as it ensures that the letter at each node is surrounded by the same amount of padding. However, I consider this to look bad and would like all circles to have the same radius.

I have tried various options to control the circle size, without success. How can I make all the circles have the same size? In addition, I think the circles are a bit too big as they are now, so I would like to reduce the padding inside the circle. It would be nice if I could set this in an option so that I could experiment with different values to see what looks best.

Comment: Please post complete minimal examples as it makes it much easier to help and helps other users to understand whether your question concerns the same issue they are struggling with.

Comment: Sure, will do next time. Sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `forest` is based on `tikz`, you can use `tikz` shape's definition as 
 `minimum size`, `text width`, `font`, etc in forest nodes style definitions in `for tree={...}`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

    \begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw, 
            minimum size=1.5em, % <-- added
            inner sep=1pt}      % <-- added
  [A
    [B
      [C
        [E]
        [F]]
      [D]]
    [G
      [H]
      [I
        [J]
        [K
          [L]
          [M]]]]]
\end{forest}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This solved my problem. It looks so easy now that I see your solution, but from reading the forest and tikz documentation it wasn't clear how to do it. Many thanks!

Comment: @Robert, from "forest" it is difficult to see "trees" ... :) however, after many times readings and experiments you will become more familiar and experienced,. Happy TeX-ing!