# Adjusting leaf sizes in forest

Tags: forest, scaling, trees

I'm trying to draw some trees using the forest package. For some reason, the leaf sizes are scaled differently depending on how many leaves the tree has (see picture).

I want every leaf to be of same size for all the three trees in the picture. How can I do that?[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^e_0$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_1$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^e_2$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_3$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}
        [$S^{e+1}_0$, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}]
        [$S^{e+1}_1$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}]
        ]
      [$S^{e+1}_2$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^{e+1}_3$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+1}_4$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^{e+2}_0$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+2}_1$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [$S^{e+2}_2$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{...} \label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be possible that the circles in the first example are smaller because their content takes up less space?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366716/134144

Comment: @leandriis I tried the proposed solution in the link. Didn't work though.

Comment: Do you also want to enlarge the empty circles?

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: @leandriis Nope, empty circles are fine. Just the leaves.

Comment: Pleas extend your code fragment to comple document which we can compile as it is.

Comment: @Zarko Done. Hope this one is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an appropriate value of `minimum size`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^e_0$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_1$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^e_2$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_3$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}
        [$S^{e+1}_0$,minimum size=3em, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}]
        [$S^{e+1}_1$, minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}]
        ]
      [$S^{e+1}_2$, minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^{e+1}_3$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+1}_4$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw}
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^{e+2}_0$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+2}_1$,minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [$S^{e+2}_2$, minimum size=3em,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{...} 
\label{fig:...}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This also uses the `minimum width` key like [leandriis' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523985/194703) but appends it to all nodes that have no children. Further simplification can be achieved by defining a style that gets used in all trees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{my tree/.style={for tree={circle,
    draw,
    where n children=0{minimum width=3em}{}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{forest}
my tree
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^e_0$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_1$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^e_2$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^e_3$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
my tree
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}
        [$S^{e+1}_0$, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}}]
        [$S^{e+1}_1$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}]
        ]
      [$S^{e+1}_2$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}}
      [$S^{e+1}_3$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+1}_4$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
  ] 
]
\end{forest}
~
\begin{forest}
my tree
[
    [, edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} 
      [$S^{e+2}_0$,edge label={node[midway,left] {0}} ] 
      [$S^{e+2}_1$,edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ] 
    ]
    [$S^{e+2}_2$, edge label={node[midway,right] {1}} ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{...} 
\label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could remove the need for adding the `$` signs by using `math content` but in this very example I personally would find this confusing.

Comment: Great simplification that will definitely save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366716/how-do-i-set-the-circle-radius-in-a-forest-tree-drawing), with some simplification of writing edge labels and slightly redesign of of trees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\tikzset{Circle/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=8pt, inner sep=0pt}}
\forestset{
  EL/.style 2 args={% shortens for (my) edge label
    edge label={node[midway, font=\footnotesize, #1]{#2}},
                    },
        }% end of forestset
\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw,
            minimum size=2em, % <-- added
            inner sep=1pt}      % <-- added
[,Circle
    [, Circle, EL={left}{0}
      [$S^e_0$, EL={left}{0} ]
      [$S^e_1$, EL={right}{1}]
    ]
    [, Circle, EL={right}{1}
      [$S^e_2$,EL={left}{0}]
      [$S^e_3$,EL={right}{1}]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\bigskip
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw,
            minimum size=2em, % <-- added
            inner sep=1pt}      % <-- added
[,Circle
    [, Circle, EL={left}{0}
      [, Circle, EL={left}{0}, fit=band
        [$S^{e+1}_0$, EL={left}{0}]
        [$S^{e+1}_1$,  EL={right}{1}]
        ]
      [$S^{e+1}_2$, EL={right}{1} ]
    ]
    [, Circle, EL={right}{1}
      [$S^{e+1}_3$, EL={left}{0}]
      [$S^{e+1}_4$, EL={right}{1} ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\quad
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw,
            minimum size=2em, % <-- added
            inner sep=1pt}      % <-- added
[,Circle
    [, Circle,  EL={left}{0}, fit=band
      [$S^{e+2}_0$, EL={left}{0} ]
      [$S^{e+2}_1$, EL={right}{1} ]
    ]
    [$S^{e+2}_2$,  EL={right}{1} ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{...}
\label{fig:...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]